# Plotly starts at the wrong slider step even after specifying

Tags: r, error-handling, plotly, slider

I have the code below, and the problem is that the slider doesn't start in the middle position - it starts at position 4/5 at where `t=650` instead of 600. The graph shown on the picture is correctly the one from the middle position (`t=600`). Meanwhile, the title shows at `t=700`, but let's ignore that for now unless you know why.

```
library(plotly)

x <- seq(0, 50, by = 0.1)
t_values <- seq(500, 700, by = 50)  # Adjusted t values

# Fixed y-axis range
y_range <- c(0, get_density(0, inc, 700, get_u(inc, 700, target_population)))  # Adjust this to your desired y-axis range

# create steps and plot all traces
steps <- list()
fig <- plot_ly()

aval <- list()
slider_steps <- list()

initial_slider_value <- 600  # Initial slider value

for (i in 1:length(t_values)) {
  t_value <- t_values[i]
  # Update u value based on the current t value
  u <- get_u(inc, t_value, target_population)

  # Update the border and population based on the new u value
  border_value <- get_border(target_border, inc, t_value, u)
  population_value <- get_population(inc, t_value, u)

  # Update the title to include the current t_value
  title_text <- paste("Transport cost:", t_value)

  aval[[i]] <- list(visible = t_value == initial_slider_value,  # Show line for the initial slider value
                    name = paste0('v = ', t_value),
                    x = x,
                    y = get_density(x, inc, t_value, u))

  fig <- add_lines(fig, x = aval[i][[1]]$x, y = aval[i][[1]]$y, visible = aval[i][[1]]$visible,
                   name = aval[i][[1]]$name, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', hoverinfo = 'name',
                   line = list(color = '00CED1'), showlegend = FALSE)

  step <- list(args = list('visible', rep(FALSE, length(aval))),
               method = 'restyle')
  step$args[[2]][i] = TRUE
  steps[[i]] = step

  # Define the slider step
  slider_steps[[i]] <- list(
    label = t_value,
    method = 'restyle',
    args = list('visible', rep(FALSE, length(t_values)))
  )
  slider_steps[[i]]$args[[2]][i] = TRUE
}

# Find the index of the initial slider value
initial_slider_index <- which(t_values == initial_slider_value)

# add slider control to plot
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(sliders = list(
    list(currentvalue = list(prefix = "Transport cost: "),
         steps = slider_steps,
         active = initial_slider_index  # Set the initial active slider
    )
  ),
  title = title_text,  # Set the initial title
  yaxis = list(range = y_range),  # Set fixed y-axis range
  xaxis = list(range = c(0, 50))  # Set the desired x-axis range
  )

fig
```

So I specifically specify, that I want it to start at the 600 mark (in the middle).

[image]

If you want to test the code, add this above:

```
alpha = 0.86 # Expenditure share on all other goods
beta = 0.6 # Cost share of housing capital in housing production function
g = 0.0005 # Scaling on housing production function
theta = 3 # Radians available for construction (benchmark is 3)
target_population <- 2000000
target_border <- 40
inc <- 70000
t <- 600
ra <- 45000
u <- 5353.65
x <- 0

get_price <- function(x,inc,t,u) {
  (((alpha^alpha) * ((1 - alpha)^(1 - alpha)) * (inc - t * x)) / u)^(1 / (1 - alpha))
}

get_quantity <- function(x,inc,t,u) {
  (((1 - alpha) * (inc - t * x)) / (((alpha^alpha) * ((1 - alpha)^(1 - alpha)) * (inc - t * x)) / u)^(1 / (1 - alpha)))
}

get_capital_intensitinc <- function(x,inc,t,u) {
  (1 / (get_price(x,inc,t,u) * (beta) * (g)))^(1 / (beta - 1))
}

get_rent <- function(x,inc,t,u) {
  (get_price(x,inc,t,u) * (g)) * ((1/(get_price(x,inc,t,u) * (beta) * (g)))^(beta / (beta - 1))) - 1 * ((1 / (get_price(x,inc,t,u) * (beta) * (g)))^(1 / (beta - 1)))
}

get_far <- function(x,inc,t,u) {
  (g) * get_capital_intensitinc(x,inc,t,u)^(beta)
}

get_density <- function(x,inc,t,u) {
  get_far(x,inc,t,u) / get_quantity(x,inc,t,u)
}

get_border <- function(target_border,inc,t,u) {
  uniroot(\(x) get_rent(x,inc,t,u) - ra, lower = 0, upper = 100)$root
}

get_population <- function(inc,t,u) {
  theta * integrate(\(x) {x * get_density(x,inc,t,u)},lower = 0, upper = get_border(target_border,inc,t,u))$value
}

get_u <- function(inc,t,target_population) {
  uniroot(\(u) get_population(inc,t,u) - target_population, c(4500, 6500))$root
}

u <- get_u(inc,t,target_population)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[R lists are indexed starting from 1](https://sudo-labs.github.io/r-data-science/vectors/). [Plotly's slider is indexed from 0](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/sliders/#layout-sliders-items-slider-active). Just subtract 1 from whatever you get out of `which(...)`'ing the list before handing it to `active`.